# dictsort or dictsortreverse doesn't work second time in same template of Django, How can I do that?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Here is my template code in template.html file

```
{% for obj in dictionary|dictsort:"name" %}
   do something
{%endfor%}
{% for obj in dictionary|dictsort:"age" %}
   do other thing
{%endfor%}
```

but in second iteration there is nothing hapening, on the first iteration everything is ok.

Comment: What is dictionary variable?

Comment: here is my views.py file code. I hope you can understand what is that dictionary 
   
views.py.  
`dictionary = Dictionary.objects.all()
context = { 'dictionary' : dictionary}
return render(request,"template.html",context)`

so here in template.html I accessed the dictionary. a collection of dictionary which are retrieved from database

Comment: Is age a field or a method on `Dictionary`?

Comment: A field, I want the values should be sorted first time depend on name on a table, and second time sorted depend on age in another table